# Add SELECT DISTINCT ORDER BY to SQL Server VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I need to create a SQL VIEW (in Azure SQL Server) of the working statement below. I have tried many variations from Stack Overflow to no avail.

**Code that returns exactly what I need:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CAST (valueColumn AS INT)
FROM dbo.valueDB
ORDER BY CAST (valueColumn AS INT)
```

**When prefixing this code with...**

```
CREATE VIEW [distinctValues]
AS
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Started executing query at Line 1

Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure distinctValues, Line 7
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

I've tried inserting `TOP (100) PERCENT` into the statement and cannot get it to work. I've also [read this is a "hack" of sorts and shouldn't be used in production](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4488/avoid-order-by-in-sql-server-views/).
So how do I get the statement I want created as a VIEW?

Comment: You can't. A view, like a table, is logically unordered. The rows of a resultset have no specific order if the query creating it does not order the rows. The link you posted tells you EXACTLY THIS - there is no solution and only hacks are not 100 percent reliable.

Comment: @ericOnline, I hope that your question was answered. If so, can you consider to mark it as such one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE in the view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW vwYourView
AS

    WITH AllValues
    AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            intValue = CAST (valueColumn AS INT)
            , intRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST (valueColumn AS INT) ORDER BY CAST (valueColumn AS INT))
        FROM dbo.valueDB
        )
    SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT intValue
    FROM AllValues
    WHERE intRank = 1
    ORDER BY intValue
```

Comment: Although this will not cause an error, it will not guarantee ordering of results. The only way to ensure ordering is with an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement that uses the view.

Comment: @DanGuzman, do you have a working example you can post of an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @ericOnline, not tested but the view would be `CREATE VIEW distinctValues AS SELECT DISTINCTCAST (valueColumn AS INT) AS valueColumn FROM dbo.valueDB;`. The query from the view would be  `SELECT valueColumn FROM distinctValues ORDER BY valueColumn;`

Answer (score 0):

No doubts that the most right way is:

```
SELECT valueColumn FROM vwYourView ORDER BY valueColumn
```

However, it happens that ETL or BI specific tools allow **you only to perform a select of tables/views, but not write SQL** and order of the data is important.

At least for now the workaround seems still valid to get a desired result in such cases:

```
CREATE VIEW vwYourView
AS
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP (9223372036854775807)  CAST (valueColumn AS INT) AS valueColumn
FROM dbo.valueDB
ORDER BY valueColumn
```

from the article mentioned in OP message:

> Of course. There are always going to be ways to get SQL Server to bend
>   to your will, even if only temporarily - **by using a percentage so
>   close to 100 percent that it will round up, or by using the upper
>   bound of the BIGINT type**: